# Safe to override save method in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, active-record-query

In a particular class that extends `ActiveRecord::Base`, I need to update a different ActiveRecord object whenever this one is created. Is it safe to override the `save` method and do the following in the save?

```
def save
  super
  other = self.other
  other.name = self.name
  other.save!
end
```

I'm worried about potential transaction related issues. I assume this would all be 1 transaction, if any part fails, everything is rolled back?

Comment: you would need to allow for a hash paramater because update_attribute uses this method and passes in a paramater.
`def save args = {} super args ...`
but the accepted answer below to use callbacks is much safer and better as I do not know if this covers all situations save is used for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you wouldn't use the hooks provided for this purpose?

You've got `after_create`, `after_save`, `after_update`, `before_create`, `before_save`, `before_update` - and a bunch of others. Wouldn't one of those be suitable?

In fact, given what you've said, it sounds like `before_save` is what you want, as you can catch any errors that occur whilst saving the second model and prevent the first one from being saved (by returning false from the `before_save` call).

Comment: Glad I could assist :) Good luck.